# Solution to $b_n=b_{n-1}+2b_{n-2}+n+1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I want to solve the equation
$$\tag{1}
b_n=b_{n-1}+2b_{n-2}+n+1
$$
I know that the solution can be written as the sum of the solution sequence $\{b_n^{(h)}\}$ to the associated homogenous equation and a particular solution $\{b_n^{(p)}\}$. The associated homogeneous equation is
$$\tag{2}
b_n^{(h)}=b_{n-1}+2b_{n-2}
$$
and I found that the solution is the sequence $\{b_n^{(h)}\}$ with
$$\tag{3}
b_{n}=\frac{1}{3}\left(2 b_{0}-b_{1}\right)(-1)^{n}+\frac{1}{3}\left(b_{0}+b_{1}\right) 2^{n}
$$
However, I am unsure how to find the particular solution $\{b_n^{(p)}\}$. I tried using the trial solution $b_n^{(p)}=cn+d$, but I did not get the right result.

Comment: Can you state what happens when you used the trial solution of $cn+d$? What did you do, and why didn't it work?

Comment: $b_n^p=cn+d$ should work fine you get $c=-1/2$

Comment: I might have made a mistake, but by using $b_n^{(p)}=cn+d$ I found $c=-1/2$ and $d=1/2$, which does not give the right sequence. I will try and go through the calculations again.

Comment: you should find $d=-7/4$ your $c$ is corect though

Comment: I tried again and now found $c=-1/2$ and $d=-7/8$. I'll try and see if I get the correct sequence both with $d=-7/8$ and with $d=-7/4$ as you suggested.

Comment: You should find $d=-7/4$ i added my answer and calculation I did .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$b_n=b_{n-1}+2b_{n-2}+n+1$$
The guess is $$b_n=cn+d$$:
$$cn+d =c(n-1)+d+2(c(n-2)+d)+n+1$$
$$-c+2cn-4c+2d+n+1=0$$
$$-5c+1+2d+n(2c+1)=0$$
$$  2c+1=0 \implies c=-\dfrac 12$$
$$\dfrac 5 2 +1+2d=0 \implies d=-\dfrac 74$$
So that:
$$b_n=c_1(-1)^n+c_22^n-\dfrac n2-\dfrac 74$$

---

For $b_1=b_0=1$
$$b_0=c_1+c_2-\dfrac 74$$
$$c_1+c_2=\dfrac {11}4$$
Then
$$b_1=-c_1+2c_2-\dfrac 12-\dfrac 74$$
$$-c_1+2c_2=\dfrac {13}4$$

Then we have:
$$c_1=\dfrac 34, c_2=2$$
$$b_n=c_1(-1)^n+c_2(2^n)-\dfrac n2-\dfrac 74$$
$$b_n=\dfrac 34(-1)^n+2(2^n)-\dfrac n2-\dfrac 74$$
$$b_2=\dfrac 34+2(2^2)-\dfrac 22-\dfrac 74$$
$$\implies b_2=6$$
As expected.

Comment: I would assume that if I have the right result, then $b_{n-1}+2 b_{n-2}+n+1=b_n^{(h)}+b_n^{(p)}$ for any $n$ and any initial conditions, but that is not what I find when I use $b_n^{(p)}=-1/2n-7/4$. However, I do get that $b_{n-1}+2 b_{n-2}=\frac{1}{3}\left(2 b_{0}-b_{1}\right)(-1)^{n}+\frac{1}{3}\left(b_{0}+b_{1}\right) 2^{n}$ so it seems that my solution to the associated homogenous equation is correct.

Comment: But it cannot be, because when I calculate explicitly  $b_{n}=b_{n-1}+2 b_{n-2}+n+1$, and my solutions I do not get the same numbers. For example, with $b_0=1, b_1=1$, for $n=4$ we get $b_{n-1}+2 b_{n-2}+n+1=59$, but my solution gives 141/8.

Comment: You dont have initial conditions so the coefficents are not known @Hydrogen

Comment: I used $b_0=1, b_1=1$ as example.

Comment: Ok and then wha is exactly the problem you faced @Hydrogen

Comment: That when I calculate $b_n=b_{n−1}+2b_{n−2}+n+1$ for a given $n$, I do not get the same value as in my solution.

Comment: Then you get $b_2=6$ it's a recurence formula @Hydrogen

Comment: Yes. $b_2=6, b_3=12, b_4=29$. But in my solution, $b_2=9/8, b_3=21/8, b_4=65/8$.

Comment: If I only calculate for the homogenous equation, I get the same values in my solution.

Comment: I calculated with the fomula I posted  I got $b_2=6 $ as expected: for $b_0=b_1=1$ @hydrogen

Comment: I added my calculation for $b_2$ I hope this may helps

Comment: Thank you very much. So I guess the mistake was that the coefficients ($\frac{1}{3}\left(2 b_{0}-b_{1}\right)$ and $\frac{1}{3}\left(b_{0}+b_{1}\right))$  that I used for the homogenous solution changes when we consider the non-homogenous equation.

Comment: Maybe yes. It's the initail conditions that gives us the unknown coeffients $c_1,c_2$ @Hydrogen

Comment: Yes, but my coefficients were dependent on the inital conditions. They worked for any $b_0$ and $b_1$ for the associated homogenous equation, but apparently it did not translate to the nonhomogenous equation.

Comment: Yes you're right. It's better to write just coefficients without $b_1$ and $b_0$ @Hydrogen  It's more simple.